# How to set up sunspot using Capistrano on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have read the answer for a similar question asked on SO before, but could not make heads or tails of it. 
I installed the suspot_rails gem and followed other steps to set up sunspot on my local box using the instructions mentioned on railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot). 
My personal website ( http://www.dahotre.com ) is hosted on Dreamhost & I need to set up sunspot. I have been using Capistrano for deploying stuff to production by a simple command: cap deploy. 
Could anyone list please list the steps I need to perform to deploy solr to production using this setting. 
I understand that I need to create a place for solr to exist on production because the sunspot.yml file says:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
```